# Confidence calculation in the performqnce of an ML algorithm knowing the sample size and number of features?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, estimation

This might be a basic question, but I was wondering if it's possible to create a score that tells how confident we can be in a certain dataset. Maybe a score that tells how likely we are to estimate the mean of the data with good accuracy?

Assuming we have a dataset normally distributed, can we use the number of rows, number of features (and maybe even the data itself) to say that it has a certain score (ranging from 0 to 1) that tells how confident we are in the performance of an ML algorithm (e.g) LR that runs on this data?